# How website domain and DNS Server on a dedicated windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have a dedicated windows 2003 stardad server. I would like to use it as my DNS server as well. I've sucefully installed DNS staff but I haven't found any good step by step so I would setup each of my domain.

Does anyone how simply do it? Would someone point me somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google gives [This Tutorial](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/dns2003/) for an internal DNS.

Also, make sure you already have the following:

- DNS Name
- Network information (Subnet information, IP Addresse Range for DHCP assignment etc..)